# GCP Pub/Sub ack for multiple subscribers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe

### **Background**:

I have a publisher with 2 subscribers on GCP pub/sub, both the subscribers run a NodeJS code & acknowledge once the process is done.

### **Issues:**

1. How can I know which subscriber has ack the message?
2. Say I have only 1 subscriber and I have sent 10 messages at once (in parallel) and 2 have failed, how can I know which 2 messages were failed? Is there any mapping between ackId and message sent on GCP pub/sub?

Answer (score 1):

The acknowledgement sent when a subscriber receives a message is separate from the acknowledgement sent to the publisher when Cloud Pub/Sub saves the message and makes it available to subscriptions. This is by [design](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/architecture#data_plane_-_the_life_of_a_message), Pub/Sub wants the senders of messages to be decoupled from the receivers of messages.

When publishing a message fails it is [automatically retried](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#retry) unless the error doesn't warrant a retry. The Nodejs client library supports custom retry settings and the documentation gives an example to know which messages have been published.

Comment: the ack that is sent back from the subscriber is the one that should only ack it for that subscriber, correct? All I see, even when using subscrbers in different VMs, is that only one gets the message. also without sending an ack. It seems random even, is it because I run two docker instances and Pub/Sub tries to figure out if they are different on a network level and thinks they're not?

Comment: I found that I need different subscribers, unlike I found in documentation. then it works as expected.